# Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ (open set) and $f:U\longrightarrow V$ a homeomorphism then we can say that $V$ is a open set in $\mathbb{R}^n\,?$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ (open set) , $V\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:U\longrightarrow V$ a homeomorphism then we can say that  $V$ is a open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Google for the theorem of «Invariance of Domain» and its consequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this result goes by the name [Invariance of Domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) and is due to Brouwer.  It's a non-trivial result.

Comment: To add to the above comment:  An homeomorphism is in particular an open function, so maps open sets to open sets.

Comment: @Manos: It is assumed that the map $f:U \rightarrow V$ is a homoemorphism, _not_ that $f$ is the restriction of a homoemorphism $\tilde{f}:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. The fact that $f$ is a homeomorphism tells you nothing about whether $V$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$. It only tells you that if $U'$ is open in $U$, then $f(U)$ is open in $V$.

Comment: Got it got it :)